# Mysql dump from server a to file on server b

Tags: mysql

I cannot perform a mysqldump on the local host due to space restrictions. I can only find methods for doing a dump to a local file or directly into a sql database on another server.

Is there a way to make a dump to a file on a remote server?

I'm using MySQL 5.1.

Comment: Yes - create a writable network share using a disk with plenty of space :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access to the remote server, you can pipe the output to the `ssh` command:

```
mysqldump <params> | ssh user@server 'cat > dumpfile.sql'
```